# Here API - TMC to GPS coordinates

Tags: java, geospatial, here-api

Been struggling to map TMC location codes to GPS coordinates for traffic flow data from the Here API

https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/dev_guide/docs/location-referencing-tmc.html

I can see here it might be possible from Java - does anyone know the direct (API key, not app code) API URL? The TMC tables for Australia do not seem to be available on the internet.

Alternatively does anyone know why when specifying shape location params instead, it doesn't have nearly as many results on the flow API?

Answer (score 0):

How to get a TMC tables for Australia is available here https://demo.support.here.com/pde/layer?region=AUS&release=latest&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=LINK_TMC_FC3

Search please all LINK_TMC layers FC1-FC5 on https://demo.support.here.com/pde/layers?region=AUS&release=latest&url_root=pde.api.here.com

There you find the description of TMC code: *Comma separated list of TMC point locations, to wards whom this link leads. Format:
Country Identifier (1 letter), Location Table Number (1...99), TMC Path Direrction (+-PN), Point Location Number (1...65535), driving direction on link (F=from reference node, T=to reference node)
Example: D1+10863F*

How to get LINK_TMC tiles along a route please look at this example: https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/map_attributes_along_route

Example requests get traffic flow by corridor with radius 100m in Sydney:

get shapes: https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow?in=corridor:BG1zvzgC-83sgJNBjI7BjDTzFTvCTvCAjD4hB7BkSvC4X7BkS3DokBnBgP7B4X7B8QAoGjIgrC_E84BTwHTgKnBsTTsOjIA_EAnGTjrBnGriBrEjS7B_JT7LTvgB_E7uBnGvR7BvvBrE_TjDvH7BzF7BnGvCjNrEjIvCvH7BzFnB3DT_ET3NvC_iB7GrdzF_ET_J7BzKvC7LvCnLvCnGnB7GnBrET3InBzFTnGTnGTjInBjInB_J7B7GnBvHnB3I7B7GnB7GnBnGTnGTvHTvHAvHUnGUvWTvRAzFA_EAnGAvHA7GAjNU3IUzFA_EAzPoBrJAvMTjITvHTzFT_JnB_JnBrO7B3wBzF_JnB7LnB7L7B7GTrOT7GTrJTnLnBrET3I7BrET7GnBzUrE3I7BvMvC7L7BzFT_ETjInBzFT_JnB3InBvHnBnGnB7GnBnLvCvR3DzZzFjX_EjSrE3czFrOjDjS3D36BzKzFT_EnBvHvC_E7BrEnBrEnB3I7B7GnBvWjDnLnBrO7B7V3DjSvCnGT_JnB_ETjIA7GUzFUnGA7LA3NTzPvCzK7BrJ7B3I7BjI7BzPjDnLvCzFnB3I7BnQrE_YnG3cvHzPrEvMjDvb7GriBrJna7GzP3DzFTzFAjIUzK8GrJkIrJ4I7LsJrO8L_JwHjcsTUwCT4D7BwCvCoBjD7BnBvC7VgU_sBokBvWwRnf7Q7G3DvHrEztB_Y3N3I7BT74Brd_EjDrEvC3D7BjDnBjDnB3DT3DA_JsJjDkDjD4DjDsErE8G7BsO7BkNTgFnB4IjD8VnBsJnBwHTkDnB4DkhB4SmNzG;r=100&apikey=***&locationReferencing=shape

get tmc: https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow?in=corridor:BG1zvzgC-83sgJNBjI7BjDTzFTvCTvCAjD4hB7BkSvC4X7BkS3DokBnBgP7B4X7B8QAoGjIgrC_E84BTwHTgKnBsTTsOjIA_EAnGTjrBnGriBrEjS7B_JT7LTvgB_E7uBnGvR7BvvBrE_TjDvH7BzF7BnGvCjNrEjIvCvH7BzFnB3DT_ET3NvC_iB7GrdzF_ET_J7BzKvC7LvCnLvCnGnB7GnBrET3InBzFTnGTnGTjInBjInB_J7B7GnBvHnB3I7B7GnB7GnBnGTnGTvHTvHAvHUnGUvWTvRAzFA_EAnGAvHA7GAjNU3IUzFA_EAzPoBrJAvMTjITvHTzFT_JnB_JnBrO7B3wBzF_JnB7LnB7L7B7GTrOT7GTrJTnLnBrET3I7BrET7GnBzUrE3I7BvMvC7L7BzFT_ETjInBzFT_JnB3InBvHnBnGnB7GnBnLvCvR3DzZzFjX_EjSrE3czFrOjDjS3D36BzKzFT_EnBvHvC_E7BrEnBrEnB3I7B7GnBvWjDnLnBrO7B7V3DjSvCnGT_JnB_ETjIA7GUzFUnGA7LA3NTzPvCzK7BrJ7B3I7BjI7BzPjDnLvCzFnB3I7BnQrE_YnG3cvHzPrEvMjDvb7GriBrJna7GzP3DzFTzFAjIUzK8GrJkIrJ4I7LsJrO8L_JwHjcsTUwCT4D7BwCvCoBjD7BnBvC7VgU_sBokBvWwRnf7Q7G3DvHrEztB_Y3N3I7BT74Brd_EjDrEvC3D7BjDnBjDnB3DT3DA_JsJjDkDjD4DjDsErE8G7BsO7BkNTgFnB4IjD8VnBsJnBwHTkDnB4DkhB4SmNzG;r=100&apikey=***&locationReferencing=tmc

you can see for both(shape & tmc) above urls(don't forget to set your apikey) response 106 traffic location at this moment.

Route in FlexiblePolyline: https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline

Please use Route v8 API(https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/index.html) to get route shape in FlexiblePolyline format.
Playground route calculation: https://demo.routing.ext.here.com/

Some tools to decode/encode flexible polyline https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/spatial_tools

Comment: Thank you! One last question; the v7 traffic flow API seems to be working much better, however higher functional class roads don't show up in responses (>4) even when specific in the request parameters - why is that?